# boost exception with RCF on linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, fedora

i am having this problem with boost , **C++** ,

i installed a new **boost on fedora14 (boost 1.44)**,

i am linking with **RCF library** which uses boost , and i am also linking with boost , the compilation is ok , but ar run time , i get the following error :

```
src/RCF/MethodInvocation.cpp:413: Assertion failed. !mVecPtr || mVecPtr.unique() . Values: 
Denver: include/RCF/util/Assert.hpp:88: virtual util::AssertFunctor::~AssertFunctor(): Assertion `0 && "See line above for assertion details."' failed
```

Comment: I don't know the library but... it supports boost 1.35 up to 1.50 ( http://www.deltavsoft.com/doc/rcf_user_guide/AppendixBuilding.html#rcf_user_guide.AppendixBuilding.Libraries ) so no issues there as I think you guessed. So do you need to update your RCF as well? https://github.com/mkotsbak/librcf-cpp/blob/master/src/RCF/MethodInvocation.cpp seems to put the assert on a different line to the error you pasted...

Comment: I think the *new* boost is 1.53 or higher...

Comment: @YZ.learner it is, but it looked to me like this lib supports only up to 1.50...

Answer (score 0):

The failed assertion comes from an incorrect use of the RCF library. Such incorrect use can not always be detected by the compiler (or rather, it can rarely be detected by the compiler).

One possible cause for the assertion is that there are multiple copies of a MethodInvocationRequest at the same time.